# sbt ~ to trigger on files outside project…?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I have made a sourceGenerator plugin that builds yaml files into Scala sources. The yaml file of necessity lies outside of the project using the sourceGenerator. This works fine in all ways except triggered execution.

I've verified this by adding a nonsense file within the project to watch too and that triggers the build just fine:

```scala
    openApiGenerate / fileInputs := openApiAllInputFiles.value
    openApiGenerate / fileInputs += (baseDirectory.value / "test.txt").toGlob,
```

The culprit is at the use site:

```scala
openApiAllInputFiles := Seq((baseDirectory.value / ".." / ".." / "api-schema").toGlob / **)
```

```
sbt:reportingHttpApi> show openApiGenerate / fileInputs
[info] * /[myproject]/reporting/http-api/../../api-schema/**
[info] * /[myproject]/reporting/http-api/test.txt
```

Running ~openApiGenerate and then editing any of the real input files under api-schema does not trigger a rebuild, while editing test.txt triggers it fine.

I've tried adding into watchTriggers too, but that doesn't help.

Is there anyway to fix this without relying on soft links?

Answer (score 0):

Relative files outside the subproject doesn't seem to work in any way I've tried but for my use case it was easy enough to just use `ThisBuild` to get the root:

```
openApiAllInputFiles := Seq((ThisBuild / baseDirectory).value / "api-schema").toGlob / **)
```